# How to optimize SQLite database fetching time

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite, query-optimization

My database has 6384 records and I am using the below query:

```
SELECT T.t_name, S.s_code, S.s_name, R.s_code, R.s_name, M.arrival_time, L.arrival_time, M.dest_time, M.train_id, S.id, R.id
FROM TRAIN_SCHEDULE M,
     TRAIN_SCHEDULE L,
     TRAIN T,
     STATION S,
     STATION R
WHERE S.s_name = 'Versova'
  AND R.s_name = 'Ghatkopar'
  AND M.arrival_time > '00:00:00'
  AND M.arrival_time < L.arrival_time
  AND M.train_id = L.train_id
  AND M.dest_time = L.dest_time
  AND T.id = M.train_id
  AND S.id = M.station_id
  AND R.id = L.station_id
```

This query takes 8 second to fetch the data.
I have also indexed my tables, but fetching time is reduced to only 2 seconds.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [STATION] (
  [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  [s_code] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  [s_name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE TRAIN_SCHEDULE(
  id INT,
  station_id INT,
  train_id INT,
  arrival_time NUM,
  departure_time NUM,
  dest_time NUM
);
CREATE TABLE TRAIN(id INT,t_name TEXT);
CREATE INDEX idx_arrival_time ON train_schedule (arrival_time);
CREATE INDEX idx_dest_time ON train_schedule (dest_time);
CREATE INDEX idx_id ON train (id);
```

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) which indexes are being used.

In this query, the database needs to scan through the `STATION` table; an index on the name column would improve this (although not by much with such a small table):

```
CREATE INDEX Station_Name ON STATION(s_name);
```

Also, lookups on the `TRAIN_SCHEDULE` table are done over multiple columns.
The query optimizer cannot use more than one index per table instance, so you should create a multi-column index.
And a column with a non-equality comparison must come last (see the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)):

```
CREATE INDEX Schedule_Station_Train_DestTime_ArrivalTime
  ON TRAIN_SCHEDULE(station_id, train_id, dest_time, arrival_time);
```

Also execute [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) once to help the optimizer pick the right index.